# Top-10 SAP HANA

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script

Is it possible to create a view to list top-N or bottom-N for consumption in design studio 1.2?

I have figured out the SQLScript needed to create a stored procedure to get me the same which is captured below -

```
BEGIN 
select 
"REGION",
"COUNTRY",
"CITY",
"Customer Name",
sum("Gross Sales"),
sum("Net Sales")
 from "USER1"."EXPO_SALES"
 GROUP BY "Customer Name",CITY,COUNTRY,REGION
 ORDER BY sum("Net Sales") Desc
 limit 10;
END;
```

How do I make bring the output into a view to consume with SAP Design Studio 1.2?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW "USER1"."EXPO_SALES_10" (
"REGION",
"COUNTRY",
"CITY", 
"Customer Name",
"SUMOFGROSSSALES",
"SUMOFNETSALES" ) 
AS SELECT 
"REGION",
"COUNTRY",
"CITY",
"Customer Name",
sum("Gross Sales"),
sum("Net Sales")
 from "USER1"."EXPO_SALES"
 GROUP BY "Customer Name",CITY,COUNTRY,REGION
 ORDER BY sum("Net Sales") Desc
 limit 10
WITH READ ONLY;
```